# How to remove the automated code posted in functions.php?

Tags: functions

There is a theme hack or a worm circulating online which adds this code to all functions.php files. It happened to me on my local server.

Here's the code - http://pastebin.com/AUsHUng1

How do I find the theme hack that creates it? Or the worm?

**UPDATE:**

I have found that this line:

```
$elem == substr(__FILE__,-13)){
```

checks for the **functions.php** file (as it's the only one having 13 letters and using file) and by using the `fputs()` functions writes itself on all **functions.php** files.

I have deleted all the instances of the code, and, hopefully, it will not replicate itself on another theme activation. I have a local server with about 60 themes.

I still haven't found the original theme that carried the code.

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

Clean all the malicious code (see my PasteBin link above) from all **functions.php** files (best to check globally using a text editor like Notepad++) and you're done. Check all downloaded themes for the code in **functions.php** file. There are more themes infected with this code online.

Comment: Dealing with hacked sites is **explicitly out of scope for WPSE**.

Comment: I know Chip, I don't want to clean it. I only need to know how it propagates, and if the infected theme contains any encoded code (like base64 or eval'd).

Comment: How can I answer my own question? Is it a common practice to do so?

Comment: @CiprianPopescu [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions - StackExchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). SO meta also has several questions on it. You can accept your own answers after 48 hours. And regardless of whether the question might be off-topic or not, it is definitely better to answer your own question in an answer than in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS MY FINAL SOLUTION:

Clean all the malicious code (see my PasteBin link above) from all functions.php files (best to check globally using a text editor like Notepad++) and you're done. Check all downloaded themes for the code in functions.php file. There are more themes infected with this code online.

*Also edited my original post. Thank you @Johannes.*

Answer (score 0):

You could always diff your most recent working backup with the *infected* website. You do have a backup don't you?

Comment: No, it's not this. I have backups, yes, and the code seems harmless. I also don't need to clean the site, I just want to know if there is a way to detect which theme is the infected one and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly turn off the code, you can use under Linux. Be very careful with the below line, as it can do a lot of harm!

```
grep -rl "add_action(\"admin_head\", \"_verify_isactivate_widget\");" --include \*.php . | xargs sed -i 's/add_action(\"admin_head\", \"_verify_isactivate_widget\");/\/\/add_action(\"admin_head\", \"_verify_isactivate_widget\");/g'
```

This comments out the line *add_action("admin_head", "_verify_isactivate_widgets");*

See [Replace a String in Multiple Files in Linux Using Grep and Sed](http://vasir.net/blog/ubuntu/replace_string_in_multiple_files)
 for an explanation how this works.